# Is the Bisq API finally "live" now or what?

Tags: p2p, decentralized-exchanges, bisq

For many years now, I've been waiting for Bisq to implement its damn API so I can begin trading (between crypto currencies, since automation is impossible with fiat).

Today, I again did a "round" to check if it has happened, and... I'm not sure? There are numerous old posts about the different APIs, and recent mentions of it, and there's this cryptic "documentation": https://mrosseel.github.io/bisq-api-examples/

But is it actually "live"? Can I start automatically trading with it today? Or is this still in some kind of "test-only" mode?

I would have asked them directly if it weren't for the fact that every single channel they provide to communicate with them refuses registration or requires weird software to be installed.

> More information: https://helloreverb.com

It's probably not a good sign that this shows some kind of generic "under construction" message...

I've browsed their official website for a long time without finding any mention of the API, so I assume that it's not live?

Comment: This looks related although I couldn't find the API docs maybe I will have to experiment with it this weekend: https://github.com/bisq-network/incubator-bisq-api/pull/2

Answer (score 1):

A Bisq gRPC API was publicly announced with the Bisq v1.9.1 release:

https://github.com/bisq-network/bisq/releases/tag/v1.9.1

Here is the gRPC API Reference (with CLI, Java, and Python examples):

https://bisq-network.github.io/slate

Those API examples are versioned at https://github.com/bisq-network/bisq-api-reference, and the project is a decent place to develop Bisq gRPC API bots.

Here is an interesting post about creating a Bisq gRPC API client or bot with Rust:

https://www.alexsears.com/2022/05/bisq-api-rust-project-setup

A related twitter account was created in May 2022:

https://twitter.com/bisq_v1_api

Answer (score 0):

I tried asking about bisq API on [twitter](https://twitter.com/prayankgahlot/status/1324445525513363456) and its a work in progress:

https://twitter.com/bisq_network/status/1324367096524890114

https://github.com/bisq-network/bisq/issues/4257